# Running Total Count until current month - DAX

Tags: dax

I'm trying to making a cummulative count over the months and it cannot cummulate on months greater then current month.

I'm using the following measure to do that:

```
Previsto_Acumulado = 
IF( SELECTEDVALUE(dCalendario[Mês]) <= MONTH(TODAY()),
CALCULATE(
    [Previsto],
    FILTER(
        ALL('dCalendario'),
        'dCalendario'[Mês] <= MAX('dCalendario'[Mês])
    )
), BLANK())
```

And the result is good, but the total columns/rows still counting to the end of year, and that cannot happens.
Anyone know how can I make the total count only until the current month?

A picture of the problem:

```
Nome do Mês Previsto_Acumulado
janeiro     2599
fevereiro   5062
março       7477
abril       10614
maio        13472
junho       16299
julho       19420
agosto      22023
setembro    25440
outubro     30123
```

[image: running totals]

Comment: Can you share your model ? your tables at least ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in the the If-statement. The total doens't just add up all values from your table. Instead it will run it once in a different context:

> - It does not matter whether a calculation is additive or non-additive.
>   Power BI computes the total by observing what is described in the DAX
>   code and generating an additive (or non-additive) total respecting the
>   developer’s intention.
> - A developer can make a non-additive measure additive by introducing an iteration. Sometimes, this is the right thing to do;
>   most often, it is not.
>   https://www.sqlbi.com/articles/why-power-bi-totals-might-seem-inaccurate/

There are build in time intelligence functions in dax that will make a running total for you like:

- TOTALYTD
- TOTALMTD
- DATESBETWEEN

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dax/time-intelligence-functions-dax

If you just need to create a running total for this year you can use the following formula:

```
Previsto_Acumulado = TOTALYTD([Previsto], 'dCalendario'[fecha])
```

If you need to make a running total for all dates in your current table you can use:

```
Previsto_Acumulado = CALCULATE([Previsto], FILTER(ALLSELECTED('dCalendario'), 'dCalendario'[Mês] <= MAX('dCalendario'[Mês]))
```